# How to get all windows from all applications with Java

Tags: java, winapi, java-native-interface

I need to get all windows from all applications. I know Java can't do things like this, but there is JNI.

I don't know how to use User32 and other DLL stuff, so I need help.

For example, there is `Window.getWindows()` which returns all windows from the current Java application, but I want to get windows from **all** applications.

To be more focused, I want solution without JNI, and if possible on the newest Java versions. If it cannot be done, I can use JNI, but as I said, I don't know how to work with JNI.

Comment: I think nobody understands your question.

Comment: You can probably do it with the Foreign Function and Memory APIs in Java 22 rather than having to write JNI code. But you will still have to work out all the Windows API calls required.

Comment: You can probably do this with JNA (specifically `jna-platform`, which covers some (but not all) of the Windows APIs).

Comment: Windows are constantly created and destroyed. If you manage to get a list of all windows in the system, the information is outdated by the time you're looking. This reads like you need to invest more time into understanding the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: This shows how to enumerate windows using [Foreign Function and Memory APIs in Java 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067484/get-titles-of-non-java-windows-in-java/75277444#75277444) plus other solutions using JNA.

Comment: @DuncG This enumerates top-level windows only, not "all windows" as requested.

Comment: @IInspectable It will be a straightforward change to add `EnumChildWindows`